# Dynamic query results into temp table

Tags: sql

I would like to play with the results of my dynamic query executable with

```
 execute sp_executesql @query; [it has many columns dependable on variables]
```

how can i export this into `#temptable`?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unless you know in advance number/type of the columns. If you do (e.g. based on variables) you can create the temp table first and then do

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXECUTE ...
```

Another possibility (not recommended) do a `SELECT INTO ##GlobalTempTable..` inside of your dynamic SQL, this way the table will be accessible to outside scope.